# Filter column "yearweek" by the top 4 highest values in df in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that follows this structure:

| yearweek | country | location | var_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

yearweek goes from 1 to 52, can it can be repeated depending on country and location.
I just want to have last 4 weeks but not selecting it manually, because I want to automate it and every week got new data.
I tried with nlargest but it just return all data of current week. This is what im triying but output is not what I want.

```
df.nlargest(4, columns = ["yearweek"], keep = 'all')
```

Any ideas?

If you need more information, just told me please

Answer (score 0):

Make a conditional statement using the max value of the column: `df[df['yearweek']>=df['yearweek'].max()-4]`

That way it will only take into account the weeks with a number superior or equal to the current week minus 4 (weeks)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).